# VBA user defined range and check if it is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have been struggling with this for over an hour. I need to write a VBA code where the user selects a range and then I check if this selected range is empty before I go and do anything else.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub test()
    Set rng= Application.InputBox("Select the range of the raw data please", Type:=8)
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(rng)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "do this, this and that!"
    End If
End Sub
```

When I run this I get a "Method Range of object_Global failed". I know it lets the user select the range just fine but the Range(rng) is not working right. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `Range(rng)` is redundant. Just write it as `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your variable `rng` is a range and you're trying to wrap that in a range, which is why it's throwing an error.  Try this instead.

```
Sub test()    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select the range of the raw data please", Type:=8)

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "do this, this and that!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @NadezhdaKarkelanova - great, happy to help.  Since this answers your questions, could you please click the check mark next to my response to accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just some code

```
 Sub main()

    Dim sentRange As Range

    Set sentRange = Application.InputBox("Select the range of the raw data please", Type:=8)


    If isRangeEmpty(sentRange) = False Then
        MsgBox "Range is not empty."
    Else
        MsgBox "Good to go!"
    End If


End Sub


Function isRangeEmpty(ByRef myRange As Range) As Boolean
    Dim rngLoop As Range
    Dim rangeEmpty As Boolean

    For Each rngLoop In myRange
        If rngLoop.Value = Empty Then
            'All Good
            isRangeEmpty = True
        Else
            'Need to exit
            isRangeEmpty = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rngLoop

End Function
```

Comment: Why would `myRange` be passed `ByRef`?

Comment: I always pass ByRef instead of ByVal for data that could be large. You could pass ByVal as you don't need the reference to actually change any data with the function.

Comment: You're passing an object pointer that's exacly, uhm, I'd guess a huge 4 bytes.

Comment: You are confused. Both `ByRef` and `ByVal` pass an object pointer. `ByRef` passes the pointer itself, `ByVal` passes a copy of it.

Comment: You could have said "Hey check out this resource on how the system works on the data behind the scenes: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx"

Comment: Since you're passing an object, you only get the pointer. `ByRef` and `ByVal` are essentially moot at that point because if you `ByVal myRange as Range` then `myRange.Value = 7`, you've change the value of the original range anyway. It doesn't matter whether you've got a _copy_ of the pointer to `Cell("a7")` or the original pointer to `Cell("a7")`. _Ignores the implicit `ActiveWorksheet` reference in `Cell(`a7")`_

Comment: What I don't like about that page is that it includes the very, **very** misleading sentence "objects are always passed by reference", which is simply wrong.

Comment: FreeMan, how would you go about passing the object as a copy, then, so data does not get manipulated?

Comment: hm, just noticed the edit on [the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57225453/vba-user-defined-range-and-check-if-it-is-empty/57225638#comment100955738_57225638). I'm sorry my "4 bytes" comment came across as snark. BTW FreeMan never got your ping, you need to @ them for that. As for passing a copy of an object, the only way to do that is to copy the object (which isn't possible for a `Range` object, a class that the user code doen't own and can't `New` up), then pass the copy - no parameter modifier deep-clones any object in VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the info @MathieuGuindon . And that explanation helps.
Would you explicitly say ByRef for objects to keep everything at a level someone later not extremely versed could still have the readability? Or leave it as a blank for objects like a range?
Through this dialogue, though, I've definitely learned a bit! Something I came across in looking into info from these comments for objects of reference type was when using ByVal you cannot change the objects 'identity', but can change the values. ByRef allows change of the identity of the object.

Comment: Careful: the (very unfortunate) implicit default in VBA *is* `ByRef`; *everything* is passed `ByRef` in VBA unless specified otherwise! I use `ByRef` when the procedure specifically needs to modify the given reference (usually naming the parameter with an `out` prefix so caller's intellisense makes it clear), otherwise `ByVal` all the way. "ByRef allows change of the identity of the object" - exactly why it's dangerous :)  I like using `Set theParameter = Nothing` in my examples; with `ByVal` everything is fine, with `ByRef` the caller throws error 91 when it later tries to use the argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only acting on the instance of data being present then something like below will work. I would also adding `Option Explicit` to the top of your code and declare all variables.

```
Sub How()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select Target Range", Type:=8)

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) <> 0 Then
    'Actions
End If

End Sub
```